# Unity3D_2019: Adding EventTriggers at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D Version 2017 you could add multiple `EventTriggers` at once by doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    EventTrigger.Entry pDown = new EventTrigger.Entry();
    pDown.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
    pDown.callback.AddListener((eventdata) => { InventorySlotCopy(); });
    slots[i].GetComponent<EventTrigger>().triggers.Add(pDown);

    EventTrigger.Entry pUp = new EventTrigger.Entry();
    pUp.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerUp;
    pUp.callback.AddListener((eventdata) => { InventorySlotInsert(); });
    slots[i].GetComponent<EventTrigger>().triggers.Add(pUp);
}
```

where `slots` is just an `array` of `GameObjects`, each with an `Image` and an `EventTrigger` attachted to it.

However, using the same code as above in Unity3D Version 2019 results in adding those `EventTriggers` but not in assigning the `functions` to the `Listener`.

[image]

How is that been done in Unity2019?

Answer (score 7):

### First of all:

You will **not see** the added listeners in the Inspector!

In the Inspector you only see the **permanent** listeners, not the ones added on runtime! These are basically [`UnityEvent<BaseEventData>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html)'s so see [Manual: UnityEvents](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html)

> When a `UnityEvent` is added to a `MonoBehaviour` it appears in the Inspector and **persistent callbacks can be added**.

The only way to add **permanent** listeners is either via the Inspector or a custom EditorScript! But this is not what you want to do here anyway.

---

I would slightly modify your script to make it more secure. I simply log some messages for the methods when they get called to show that they get called.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Rather make these directly of type EventTrigger
    // So you don't have to use GetComponent later and can be sure that these array only receives
    // objects that actually have that Component attached!
    public EventTrigger[] slots;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Instead of a hardcoded index either iterate using slots.Length
        // or simply directly foreach
        foreach (var slot in slots)
        {
            var pDown = new EventTrigger.Entry
            {
                eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown
            };

            pDown.callback.AddListener(eventData => { InventorySlotCopy(); });
            slot.triggers.Add(pDown);

            var pUp = new EventTrigger.Entry
            {
                eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerUp
            };

            pUp.callback.AddListener(eventData => { InventorySlotInsert(); });
            slot.triggers.Add(pUp);
        }
    }

    private void InventorySlotCopy()
    {
        Debug.Log(nameof(InventorySlotCopy));
    }

    private void InventorySlotInsert()
    {
        Debug.Log(nameof(InventorySlotInsert));
    }
}
```

The rest depends on your setup. We don't know what objects your `slots` are but there are basically two(three) options:

#### Option 1 - UI

If these slot objects are `UI` elements in a `Canvas` such as `Image` or `Text`.

This seems to be the case for your specifically.

1. Make sure that there is an `EventSystem` present in the scene.

   Usually one gets created when creating the first `Canvas`.

   If not create it now via `Hierachy View` → <kbd>right click</kbd> → `UI` → `EventSystem`
2. Make sure you have the option `RayCast Target` **enabled** on your slot's UI Components.

Result:

[image]

---

#### Options 2 - 3D Objects (Option 3 - 3D Objects with 2D Colliders)

Just adding this for other users.

If these objects are **not** UI elements but rather 3D objects make sure

1. Again you need the `EventSystem` as before
2. The slots have `Collider` Components attached to the same `GameObject` the `EvenTrigger` Component is attached to or any of its children (it may be nested).
3. Your `Camera` needs the Component `PhysicsRaycaster` attached. Make sure here that the `eventMask` includes the layer(s) your slot objects are placed on. (For Option 3 using 2D Colliders instead use the `Physics2DRaycaster`)

Result:

[image]

---

As you can see the methods will not be visible in the Inspector (due to the reason mentioned before) but the added listener methods still get called.